# Segmentation fault using MPI

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, mpi

I have a matrix with numbers, which I want to distribute among MPI processes (I want to divide the matrix into chunks and make that every process takes its own part). You can see that I have commented it below so that you understand:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define MASTER 0

int *data; // pointer to data
int total_elems; // total number of elems
int type_size; // size of the data type (in our case it will be int)
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
        MPI_Status status; 
        int my_rank,my_size; 
        int rc = -1; 
        int chunk; 
        int i; 

        type_size = sizeof(int);
        if (argc != 2){ 
                printf("usage: %s file_name\n",argv[0]); 
                exit(1); 
        }
        printf("Using %s as input\n",argv[1]); 
        total_elems = file_size(argv[1],sizeof(int)); // this function calculates the number of elems in the file/matrix
        if (total_elems<0){ 
                printf("Invalid number of elements\n"); 
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc); 
        }
        printf("There are %d elems in the matrix\n",total_elems); 

        MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); // initialize MPI environment
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&my_rank); 
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&my_size); 

        printf("Number of MPI processes: %d\n", my_size);
        chunk = total_elems/my_size; // elems in a chunk, a chunk for every process
        printf("Chunk size: %d\n", chunk); 
printf("up to here ok 0\n");
if (my_rank == MASTER) 
        {
             // nothing  
printf("up to here ok 0.5\n"); 
         // here it is still ok
        }else{  // NOW HERE ATTENTION!! here it is still ok
                printf("ok?\n"); // does not print this printf, i have a segmentation fault
                data = (int *)malloc(chunk*sizeof(int)); // we assign the number of bytes to the chunk 
                if (data == NULL){
                        printf("Error in malloc\n");
                        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc); 
                }

                rc = read_from_pos(argv[1], chunk*(my_rank-1), chunk, type_size, (void *)data); // a function that reads from the file from a position a specified number of elements and stores in the buffer data
                if (rc<0){ 
                        printf("Error reading file\n");
                        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
                }


        }
```

And the function 'read_from_pos':

```
int read_from_pos(char *name, uint pos,uint num_elems,uint type_size,void *buff)
{
        int fd,ret=0,pending,ready=0;
        fd=open(name,O_RDONLY); 
        if (fd<0)  return -1;
        ret=lseek(fd,(pos*type_size),SEEK_SET); // we go to the position
        if (ret!=pos*type_size) return -1;
        pending=num_elems*type_size; // pending items to be read
        ready=0; // read bytes 0 at the moment
        while(pending>0){ 
                ret=read(fd,(char *)buff+ready,pending);
                if (ret<0) return -1;
                pending=pending-ret;
                ready=ready+ret;
        }
        printf("Total number of elements read %u\n",ready/type_size);
        close(fd);
        return 0;
}
```

So, I do not understand, why in the if statement everything is still okay, but then when it goes to the else statement, when the process is not master, it does not even print the printf and it gets a segmentation fault. I am sure that a printf cannot yield a segmentation fault, I have used "\n", so my guess is the malloc, but still, I think it is okay. I have assigned the size of the chunk in the malloc for every process.

So perhaps it is because of MPI. Do I have to protect somehow this piece of code? I want an independent chunk of the matrix for every slave process, I am mistaken?

The output with a matrix of 10 numbers I get this:

```
./prog easy.txt
Using easy.txt as input
There are 10 elements in the file
There are 10 elems in the matrix
Number of MPI processes: 1
Chunk size: 10
up to here ok 0
up to here ok 0.5
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: How are you running the program? Do you define number of processes when running? For example mpirun -n 4 -f file.c

Comment: #!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=mpi_mat
#SBATCH --output=mpiout.out
#SBATCH --error=mpiout.err
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=5
#SBATCH --qos=debug
mpirun ./prog easy.txt

Comment: it is not that, I have a shell script and I use sbatch to run the script

Comment: Do you have a stack trace ? For debugging purpose, you can either add a `MPI_Barrier()` after the `if (my_rank == MASTER)` block or simply `sleep(10)` on the master rank.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet why should I add a sleep on the master rank? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Never mind ... you run only one MPI task and that is why you never enter the `else` clause. Try `mpirun -np 2 ./prog easy.txt` to start 2 MPI tasks. The crash occurs in code you did not post.

Comment: You were right @GillesGouaillardet !